# Notices Added In WordPress Are Not Dismissible

Tags: wordpress

I am working on my WordPress plugin and I have added the notices according to the requirement but the notices are not dismissible.

My Code Added:

```
if($findtext == ""){
    
 $msg= '<div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>Please enter find text.</p><button type="button" class="notice-dismiss"><span class="screen-reader-text">Dismiss this notice.</span></button></div>';

    } elseif ($replacetext == "") {
        
 $msg= '<div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>Please enter replace text.</p><button type="button" class="notice-dismiss"><span class="screen-reader-text">Dismiss this notice.</span></button></div>';

    } else {
    
 $msg= '<div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>Please select location.</p><button type="button" class="notice-dismiss"><span class="screen-reader-text">Dismiss this notice.</span></button></div>';
    }
```

I have added this code but the notice is not dismissible when clicking on the close button. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked in the bowser inspector console for javascript errors, that could make trouble, as "is_dismissible" selector class name will display a closing icon that javascript handle in Wordpress admin.Are you using the action hook `admin_notices` to display them?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec. I have added this code only. Not any action or something else.

Comment: So have a look to: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/ and use that just as the code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Using `admin_notices` hook and properly markup and removing from markup

```
<button type="button" class="notice-dismiss"><span class="screen-reader-text">Dismiss this notice.</span></button>
```

Could solve the problem.

Rewritten **PHP** code:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', function () use ( $findtext, $replacetext ) {
    if ( $findtext == "" ) {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>Please enter find text!</p></div>
        <?php

        return;
    }

    if ( $replacetext == "" ) {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>Please enter replace text.</p></div>
        <?php

        return;
    }

    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>Please select location.</p></div>

    <?php
} );
```

WordPress appends button under the hood. Don't need to append a `button` tag manually. Now notices are dismissible.

**Important to note:**

Your code show notices every time by your logic, probably it makes sense to add location checking analogically as findtext and replacetext did.